# Formatted text in Database for ASP.NET MVC3 website

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, markup

Are there any plugins or libraries for storing markup in a database that can be translated into HTML without actually storing HTML markup (to prevent cross-site scripting attacks)?

I guess what I'm looking for is an automatic, safe way to translate something like BBCode (that would be stored in the database, marking up the text) into the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), just like Stack Overflow does.

It uses [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/), as discussed in [this blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/) and [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91681/where-i-can-find-stackoverflow-markdown).